# Autoassign relationship when creating contact

Tags: relationships

I'm looking for a way to auto-assign relationships between the current drupal user and created contact. I know there is extension CiviRelate, but it only works when using "profiles". I'm looking for a way to auto-assign selected relationships when the user creates contact from the CiviCRM backend (from the dashboard).

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this with the CiviRules extension. The extension can be found here: https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules and the documentation here: https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/

You should add a rule with trigger "Contact of any type is added" and then some conditions (perhaps on contact type or contact is in group if required). You can then use the action "add relationship".

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've tried that but I think it is not the answer. Maybe I wasn't clear enough- I want to assign a relationship between added contact and current user. right now I can't see this option in CiviRules

Comment: That would mean you have to develop/get someone to develop a specific action for you. Keep this in the back of your mind if you do not find another solution. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your CMS you could consider the following

- WP: create a Caldera Form for people to add New Contacts via, and add the relationship automatically
- Drupal: as above but use Webform